# Data processing using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I have a CSV file in the format mentioned below:

```
API Name                Test Result    Risk Rating    Vulnerability Category

https://api-test.com      FAIL           LOW          Information Gathering
https://api-test1.com     PASS           MEDIUM       Authentication Test
https://api-test2.com     SKIP           HIGH         Web Service
https://api-test1.com     FAIL           CRITICAL     Configuration Management
```

I am using pandas library for data processing. Now, there could be repetition of API urls as you can see from the table. So, what I want is to get deatils of same API in Dataframe. For ex: API name variable for the API "https://api-test1.com" should contain data like this:

```
 API Name                Test Result    Risk Rating    Vulnerability Category

https://api-test1.com     PASS           MEDIUM         Authentication Test
https://api-test1.com     FAIL           CRITICAL       Configuration Management
```

Similarly variable for API2 should contain the data related to all the API2. Thanks!

Comment: Guys, why I am getting downvoted...I am not able to solve this particular problem in Pandas as I am new to this library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [.duplicated(keep=False)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) method:

```
In [138]: df['API Name'].duplicated(keep=False)
Out[138]:
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
Name: API Name, dtype: bool

In [139]: df[df['API Name'].duplicated(keep=False)]
Out[139]:
                API Name Test Result Risk Rating    Vulnerability Category
1  https://api-test1.com        PASS      MEDIUM       Authentication Test
3  https://api-test1.com        FAIL    CRITICAL  Configuration Management
```

**UPDATE:** you don't need such variables (`api1`, `api2`, etc.) as you can always easily access your data in the DataFrame:

```
In [152]: apis = df['API Name'].unique()

In [153]: apis
Out[153]: array(['https://api-test.com', 'https://api-test1.com', 'https://api-test2.com'], dtype=object)

In [154]: for api in apis:
     ...:     print(df.loc[df['API Name'] == api])
     ...:
               API Name Test Result Risk Rating Vulnerability Category
0  https://api-test.com        FAIL         LOW  Information Gathering
                API Name Test Result Risk Rating    Vulnerability Category
1  https://api-test1.com        PASS      MEDIUM       Authentication Test
3  https://api-test1.com        FAIL    CRITICAL  Configuration Management
                API Name Test Result Risk Rating Vulnerability Category
2  https://api-test2.com        SKIP        HIGH            Web Service
```

Comment: In my sheet, there are number of duplicate API urls. So, I want to extract them in separate variable which means all the details of API1 would be in one variable and so on.

Comment: @RamanBalyan, can you [post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40399301/edit) desired (expected) output (data set)?

Comment: So from the above code written by you, I am able to group together API's with same url. But, what I want is somethig like: if I print variable api1, it should contain all details of just API1. Similarly api2 variable should contain all the details of API2